# arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc: error: spawn: No such file or directory

Tags: c, linux

Hi i am using MINGW32 to compile u-boot with the cross_compiler below is the error i got,
Please advice.

[image: Error]

Comment: The PATH must contain "...arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin" containing the "arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-***.exe" programs.

Comment: wen-bin.leong@VIE-WBLEONG-NB /home/lyc/u-boot-pi-rpi/u-boot-pi-rpi
$ PATH=$PATH:/c/MinGW/msys/1.0/home/lyc/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-hardfp-gdbV1/
arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin
      and it has still the same error

Comment: Use Cross-compiler tool for windows ... as your log says its linux os cross-compiler gcc.  for windows arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc.exe ends with .exe